# providing common functionality for different viewcontrollers in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have many `viewcontrollers` which needs to have some common functionality related to navigation.

Earlier I made a base class `BaseViewController`(extending `UIViewController`) which have all common functionality (like doing some tasks on `viewDidLoad` etc) and all my `viewcontrollers` extends `BaseViewController`.

The problem is that some of my `viewcontroller` should be subclass of `UIViewController` and some of `UITableViewController`, so I can not use above approach.

One way could be to write base class for both and duplicating code. Is there any better way without duplicating code.

Comment: You can try by creating Category of UIViewController, it will  also work with UITableviewController as its subclass of a UIViewController.

Comment: You should replace inheritance with delegation: https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-inheritance-with-delegation .

Comment: in super class model I can do `viewcontroller` specific tasks in viewdidload... etc. without writing single line in child controller. using category can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can get around this by using delegation or helper objects, I would make the case for just not using `UITableViewController`. It is only a very light subclass on top of `UIViewController`, providing a table view, conforming to the delegate & data source protocols, and adding a property or two for selection & refresh.

While I wouldn't normally suggest recreating something that the framework has already done for you, it may (in your case) make your code more easy to understand if you just keep everything inheriting from a common base class and add a table view to one of the subclasses.

If you do think this would be a reasonable approach, the [`UITableViewController` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/) overview gives a detailed description of exactly what & where these behaviours are implemented, so mimicking its exact setup is trivial.

#### Adding a table view to `UIViewController`

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

In your storyboard, drag a "Table View" from the object library and drop it on top of your View Controller scene's "View" in the Document Outline - this will **replace** the root view with a `UITableView`.

Then just hook it up:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-drag from the view controller to the table view to hook up the `view` and `tableView` outlets
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-drag from the table view to the view controller to set the `delegate` and `dataSource` outlets.

Done - no magic required.

Comment: I would not prefer recreating something framework have already done either.  It would require lot of work and will be prone to bugs. How can this be done using delegation? won't every controller need to implement delegate?

Comment: @hridayesh I meant that the VCs could instead delegate out their common behaviour to another object, but it's much more messy. I really would recommend dropping `UITableViewController` for a `UIViewController` that just displays a table view, as your VCs will be much more clear & maintainable. I must stress that I think you're expecting more work than it would take; `UITableViewController` _really_ doesn't do much on top of `UIViewController`, and this type of setup is very common. What behaviour do you actually need from `UITableViewController`, beyond the table view it provides?

Comment: In my storyboard I have created `UITableViewController` and linked to `MyViewController` which extends `UITableViewController`. It just provide basic behavior of drawing cells and action on them. How can I link it to provide basic behavior if `MyViewController` doesn't extend  `UITableViewController`?

Comment: I have updated my answer to describe how to add a table view to a `UIViewController` subclass - it's really simple, and I would _definitely_ recommend it over complicating your inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Instead in my storyboard it is UITableViewController for which I set class to ViewController which is subclass of UIViewController and implements UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource protocols.